# How to check if InputElement is a checkbox in Dart

Tags: html, json, dart, dart-html

I'm serializing some forms to JSON in dart:html

```
Map jsonifyForm(String formQuery){

  FormElement form = querySelector(formQuery);

  Map<String, String> data = {};

  List<InputElement> inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input.json");
  for (InputElement input in inputs) {

    if (input is CheckboxInputElement){
      print("checkbox: " + input.name + "|" + input.checked.toString());
      data.putIfAbsent(input.name, () => input.checked);
    } else {
      print("text: " + input.name + "|" + input.value);
      data.putIfAbsent(input.name, () => input.value);
    }
  }

  print(data);
  return data;
}
```

I have about a 100 input fields on the page, followed by only one checkbox:

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control tip json" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" value="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="First Name"/>


<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control tip json" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" value="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Last Name"/>

...

<label class="form-control tip" data-placement="top" title="VAT On Goods" data-toggle="tooltip">
<input class="json" type="checkbox" name="vatOnGoods">
VAT on goods
</label>
```

When I call jsonifyForm, I'm seeing that all inputs are being treated as checkboxes:

```
checkbox: firstName|false
checkbox: lastName|false
...
checkbox: vatOnGoods|false

{firstName: false, lastName: false, ..., vatOnGoods: false}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Logged a bug:
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22967&thanks=22967&ts=1427184292

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `CheckboxInputElement` only provides the `value` and `checked` attributes. I am still wondering why it says that those are all checkboxes. But you can just check the `type` attribute:

```
if(input.type == 'checkbox')
```

to check the type of the checkbox.

Comment: Yes, I think you should do. Because the InputElements aren't clearly CheckBoxElements :) Maybe it is because of the factory constructor it is using, because it only creates an `InputElement`.